# Getting Information/Data/Values from a row in React-Table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I literally have stayed up all night trying to figure out how to grab a value from my row.

```
const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        // first group - TV Show
        Header: "Shop Chop Chop List",
        // First group columns
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "User",
            accessor: "email",
          },
          {
            Header: "Store",
            accessor: "store",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        Header: "Details",
        columns: [
          {
            Header: "Item",
            accessor: "title",
          },
          {
            Header: "Picture",
            accessor: "picture",
            Cell: ({ row }) => (
              <a
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                href={row.original.picture}
              >
                {row.original.picture}
              </a>
            ),
          },
          {
            Header: "Aisle",
            accessor: "aisleLocation",
          },
          {
            Header: "Location",
            id: 'edit',
            accessor: 'id',
            Cell: ({value}) => (
              <div>
                <button
                  onClick={()=> {
                    console.log(value);
                  }}
                  className={styles.editBtn}
                >
                  Record Aisle
                </button>
              </div>
            ),
          },
          {
              Header: "Remove",
              id: "delete",
              accessor: (str) => "delete",

              Cell: (row)=> (
                  <button
                  className={styles.deleteBtn}
                  onClick={()=> {
                      const dataCopy = [...data];
                      dataCopy.splice(row.index, 1);
                      setData(dataCopy);
                  }}>
                  Found
                </button>

              )
               
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
    [data],
  );
```

This is my latest attempt. I am trying to grab a value from  this row so I can assign a aisle location on the back end. I would prefer the uniqueID, but I could make it work with title and store as well. It is so damn hard to grab the information out of this row.

Here is my tableContainer

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import {
  useTable,
  useSortBy,
  useFilters,
  useExpanded,
  usePagination,
} from 'react-table';
import { Table, Row, Col, Button, Input} from 'reactstrap';
import { Filter, DefaultColumnFilter } from './Filters';

const TableContainer = ({ columns, data, renderRowSubComponent }) => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    page,
    prepareRow,
    visibleColumns,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    pageOptions,
    pageCount,
    gotoPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    state: { pageIndex },
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      defaultColumn: { Filter: DefaultColumnFilter },
      initialState: { pageIndex: 0, pageSize: 5 },
    },
    useFilters,
    useSortBy,
    useExpanded,
    usePagination
  );

  const generateSortingIndicator = (column) => {
    return column.isSorted ? (column.isSortedDesc ? ' ' : ' ') : '';
  };


  const onChangeInInput = (event) => {
    const page = event.target.value ? Number(event.target.value) - 1 : 0;
    gotoPage(page);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Table bordered hover {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                  <div {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                    {column.render('Header')}
                    {generateSortingIndicator(column)}
                  </div>
                  <Filter column={column} />
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>

        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {page.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <Fragment key={row.getRowProps().key}>
                <tr onClick={()=> handleShow(row.original)}>
                  {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                    return (
                      <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
                {row.isExpanded && (
                  <tr>
                    <td colSpan={visibleColumns.length}>
                      {renderRowSubComponent(row)}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                )}
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
```

Please, can anyone help? I am new so very specific instructions are desired

please, and thank you

Answer (score 0):

`react-table` is meant for displaying the data, not the JSX element but you can solve the issue in two ways, first, you can pass a unique id in the row data and just like above use that in the Cell or you can just render the JSX element as a row data and use the unique id directly(for example some model Id which you are trying to delete) but rendering the JSX element as a data is a heavy task as memoization will fail and you will have to do provide extra logic to prevent rerendering.